# Completely disabling the grip in a CStatusBar

Tags: mfc

I have a CListCtrl that creates a child CStatusBar (for displaying statistics etc).

All works fine (except for when using CMFCTabCtrl, but that's another story).

When I use this CListCtrl in a resizable dialog, it appears the framework signals the CStatusBar to automatically add a SBARS_SIZEGRIP, which I do not want.

Any ideas on how to disable this behavior for my CStatusBar?

Comment: Where and how to you create the statusbar? show us the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a CStatusBar SBARS_SIZEGRIP style is added when the parent frame has the style WS_THICKFRAME (see source code VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\barstat.cpp `CStatusBar::CreateEx`).

It should be easy to prevent this when you overwrite PreCreateWindow and remove this style.

Note that the behaviour of CMFCStatusBar is different.